# Interdocker communication - HTTP request from one docker to another fails

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have three docker containers, all running in the same docker network.  They are all deployed on a Linux Ubuntu server.

1. Nginx is my web server/reverse proxy server
2. MyDjangoApp served up by gunicorn
3. Microservice served up by tomcat

From my windows PC I can access all of my Django end points successfully.  However, one of them fails and its the one that tries to make either an http get or http post to the microservice (from my django app).  My http get request (from docker 2 to docker 3 ) looks like this:

```
http://my_ip:9000/output_annotations/
```

From my windows pc I browse to `http:my_ip:1337/microservice/output_annotations/`  and it fails with this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='standard_core_nlp', port=9000): Max retries exceeded with url: /output_annotations (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5ae38e3940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
```

When I use postman to do an http get from  `http://my_ip:9000/output_annotations` it succeeds!

When all my dockers are deployed locally everything works properly.

Here are my docker related files:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
      build: 
          context: ../..
          dockerfile: docker/pb_django/Dockerfile
          args:
            HTTP_PROXY: http://my_proxy.com:9480
            HTTPS_PROXY: http://my_proxy:9480
      image: pb_django 
      container_name: pb_django
      expose:
        - "8000"
      networks:
        - ciee_network
  nginx:
      build: ./nginx
      ports:
        - "1337:80"
      depends_on:
        - web
      networks:
        - ciee_network
networks:
  ciee_network:
    external: true
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
    FROM python:3.6
    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
    ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
    ARG HTTP_PROXY
    ARG HTTPS_PROXY
    COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
    RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
    RUN mkdir /code
    WORKDIR /code
    ADD . /code/
    RUN chmod -R 755 /code
    RUN useradd -m user
    RUN chmod 777 /home/user
    USER user
    CMD unset http_proxy
    CMD unset https_proxy
    CMD unset HTTP_PROXY
    CMD unset HTTPS_PROXY
    ENV HTTP_PROXY=
    ENV HTTPS_PROXY=
    CMD ["gunicorn", "PB_Django.wsgi:application", "--config", "docker/pb_django/gunicorn.conf", "--keep-alive", "600"]
```

**nginx Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream pb_django {
    server web:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://pb_django/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 10m;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10m;
        client_max_body_size 700m;
    }
}
```

**and finally docker-compose.yml for my microservice**

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
      build: 
          context:  ..
          dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.ca
      image: microservice  
      container_name: microservice
      ports:
        - "9000:9000"
```

**Dockerfile.ca for microservice**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV TZ=US/Central
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezon
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
COPY ./docker/scripts /scripts

RUN scripts/with-proxy.sh apt-get update -y && \
    scripts/with-proxy.sh apt-get install -y apt-utils \
        default-jre \
        default-jdk

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD ./microservice-server/target/microservice-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /code/
RUN chmod -R 755 /code
RUN useradd -m user
RUN chmod 777 /home/user
USER user
ENV PORT 9000
EXPOSE 9000
CMD java -jar /code/microservice-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you try docker linking and replacing my_ip with container name?

Comment: I've added networking -  I'm getting a different error now.

Answer (score 0):

The compose file you present here misses a link to the network that is to be common for all the containers.

Th microservice's compose file should also contain this directive:

```
  networks:
    - ciee_network
```

So its contents could look like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
      build: 
          context:  ..
          dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.ca
      image: microservice  
      container_name: microservice
      networks:
        - ciee_network
      ports:
        - "9000:9000"
```

Then the microservice endpoint should be reachable from both the `web` and `nginx` container via `http(s)://microservice:9000/`

Also:

1. There is apparently a typo in `Dockerfile.ca` on line 3 - you most likely want to write into `/etc/timezone`
2. The `python` related ENV variables (`PYTHONUNBUFFERED`, `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`) are probably unnecessary within the `dockerfile` of the `java` microservice